# How to access to a template child method from a parent class

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, casting

I have the following base class

```
//ALL possible types could be used in my project (ROOT CERN's types)
using var_t = std::variant <Bool_t, Char_t, Double_t, Float_t, Int_t, UInt_t, TString>;

class Base
{
    public :
        virtual ~Base();
        virtual void Print() const = 0;

        var_t GetValueFromChild() const;
};
```

Where `GetValueFromChild` is supposed to access to template child class method:

```
template< typename T >
class Child : public Base
{
    protected :
        const T* value;
    public :
        Child( const T* value ) : value( value ) { }
        ~Child() { }
        T GetValue() const { return *value; }
        void Print() const { std::cout << *value << "\n"; }
};
```

The problem is I don't know how to define `GetValueFromChild`. I try this approach:

```
var_t  Base::GetValueFromChild() const
{
    if ( Child* ch = dynamic_cast<Child* >( this ) )
    {
        return ch->GetValue();
    }
    else{ return /*smth*/ }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> use of class template 'TypedVariable' requires template arguments
>       if ( Child* ch = dynamic_cast( this ) )

What that (or those) argument(s) should be?

Comment: Use a virtual function like you already did for others??

Comment: Like so? `virtual var_t  GetValue()` and then override in the `Child`?

Comment: OMG. So obvious. But this works only because I have `var_t` variant?